# Unable to Create Maven Multi Module Project in wso2 Integration studio 7.0.0

Tags: maven, wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

Don't Know where the problem exactly. But when I try to create a Maven project from the Maven project template present in Miscellaneous Project Types of integration studio it won't be created in the workspace.
I have checked in the workspace directory but it was not there.

I also try to provide another directory on the local system but won't create. **Is I am missing any updates regarding Maven or any other issue?**

Below have done while creating a maven project.

1. In the maven project dialogue box, provide group Id and Artifact Id and click finish.

   [image]
   **Error details as below**

!ENTRY org.wso2.tools.eclipse.platform.core 4 0 2020-03-09 17:10:19.688
!MESSAGE ObserverFailed:
!STACK 0
org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.platform.core.exception.ObserverFailedException: An observer failed to execute properly: null
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.platform.core.project.model.ProjectDataModel.trigger(ProjectDataModel.java:234)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.platform.core.project.model.ProjectDataModel.setProjectName(ProjectDataModel.java:179)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.platform.core.project.model.ProjectDataModel.setModelPropertyValue(ProjectDataModel.java:273)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.maven.multi.module.handlers.MvnMultiModuleModel.setModelPropertyValue(MvnMultiModuleModel.java:71)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.platform.ui.wizard.pages.ProjectOptionsDataPage$23.onModifyAction(ProjectOptionsDataPage.java:1169)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.platform.ui.utils.WSO2UIToolkit$4$1.modifyText(WSO2UIToolkit.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4428)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1103)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1084)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.wmCommandChild(Text.java:3122)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_COMMAND(Control.java:4991)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4846)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5191)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2454)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.callWindowProc(Text.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4941)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.windowProc(Text.java:2704)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5178)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2560)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3815)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:818)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:794)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.templates.dashboard.web.function.server.JSEmbeddedFunctions.openWizard(JSEmbeddedFunctions.java:85)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.templates.dashboard.web.function.server.OpenIDEFunctionServlet$1$1.run(OpenIDEFunctionServlet.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4213)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3820)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.platform.ui.wizard.pages.MavenDetailsPage.setArtifactIDLabel(MavenDetailsPage.java:621)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.platform.ui.wizard.pages.MavenDetailsPage.update(MavenDetailsPage.java:609)
    at java.util.Observable.notifyObservers(Observable.java:159)
    at java.util.Observable.notifyObservers(Observable.java:115)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.platform.core.project.model.ProjectDataModel.trigger(ProjectDataModel.java:232)
    ... 53 more

Comment: @PrabushiSamarakoon can you please help me here ??

Comment: @sajithaliyanage can you assist here?

Comment: I have found a similar issue which exists in Integration Studio 7.0.0 as well. I was able to resolve it after updating 'Maven Multi Module Feature' version into 7.0.0.202002280827.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is already identified and fixed. Please update the Integration Studio 7.0.0 to get the fix.

`Help > Check for Updates > Select all updates > Install`

Comment: Yes able to do now. Thanks